# How to minimalize multiple Audio Codes

Tags: java, audio

I am trying to minimalize my code for more than one audio. This looks just awful. How can I minimalize those many codes into one good legible code.

```
public class Sound {
    public static int playerSound (char[][] gameBoard) {
        try (AudioInputStream inStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Sound.class.getResourceAsStream("Spieler x.wav")) ){
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(inStream);
            clip.start();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException lue) {
            System.out.println("Spieler x.wav" + lue.getMessage());
            lue.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException uafe) {
            System.out.println("Spieler x.wav" + uafe.getMessage());
            uafe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Spieler x.wav" + ioe.getMessage());
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public static int computerSound (char[][] gameBoard) {
        try (AudioInputStream inStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Sound.class.getResourceAsStream("Bot.wav")) ){
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(inStream);
            clip.start();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException lue) {
            System.out.println("Bot.wav" + lue.getMessage());
            lue.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException uafe) {
            System.out.println("Bot.wav" + uafe.getMessage());
            uafe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Bot.wav" + ioe.getMessage());
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, combine your exceptions:

```
try (AudioInputStream inStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Sound.class.getResourceAsStream("Spieler x.wav")) ){
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(inStream);
    clip.start();
} catch (LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Spieler x.wav " + e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Second, move the code which is identical in both methods into a separate `private` method:

```
private static void play(String resourcePath) {
    try (AudioInputStream inStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Sound.class.getResourceAsStream(resourcePath)) ){
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(inStream);
        clip.start();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException e) {
        System.out.println(resourcePath + ": " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static int playerSound(char[][] gameBoard) {
    play("Spieler x.wav");
    return 0;
}

public static int computerSound(char[][] gameBoard) {
    play("Bot.wav");
    return 0;
}
```

Third, since you always return the same value (zero), there is no point in having a return value at all:

```
public static void playerSound(char[][] gameBoard) {
    play("Spieler x.wav");
}

public static void computerSound(char[][] gameBoard) {
    play("Bot.wav");
}
```

You never make use of `gameBoard`, so that argument can be removed from the methods:

```
public static void playerSound() {
    play("Spieler x.wav");
}

public static void computerSound() {
    play("Bot.wav");
}
```

As a side note, you probably should not autoclose the AudioInputStream before the Clip has finished playing, since the Clip may still be reading from it:

```
private static void play(String resourcePath) {
    try {
        AudioInputStream inStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
            Sound.class.getResourceAsStream(resourcePath));

        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.addLineListener(e -> {
            if (e.getType().equals(LineEvent.Type.STOP)) {
                clip.close();
                try {
                    inStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        clip.open(inStream);
        clip.start();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException e) {
        System.out.println(resourcePath + ": " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mostly a very helpful answer, but if a given `Clip` is being played more than once, repeatedly loading the data from the file for each playback is very wasteful. A `Clip` will not even begin to play until the redundant open operation has completed, potentially adding latency. You should either make your `Clips`  instance variables and only open them once, or use `SourceDataLine` for playback instead of `Clip` (for longer audio files).